# Bulk delete Google Calendar events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i would like to delete calendar events that has a specialword in the event name  "Stockholm".

I got this, but it's only by date. Could it be done by keyword?

```
var fromDate = new Date(2013,0,1,0,0,0);
var toDate = new Date(2013,0,4,0,0,0);
var calendarName = 'My Calendar';

// delete from Jan 1 to end of Jan 4, 2013

var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++){
  var ev = events[i];
  Logger.log(ev.getTitle()); // show event name in log
  ev.deleteEvent();
}
```

Comment: have a look at this example that might interest you. Code is included in the shared spreadsheet.

Comment: did you mean to include a link Serge?

Answer (score 1):

`calendar.getEvents()` accepts a search option.  You just need to modify that one line:

```js
var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate, {search: 'Stockholm'});
```